# OnBoard ethernet controller: LAN cable not plugged in

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I have a following problem on Windows 7 64bit, with OnBoard Ethernet on MSI K9N Neo V2 MotherBoard: I have connected my PC to a router via UTP cable, but it can't connect to local network. I eliminated the following causes:

1. **Router issues** - Router is just fine as my other PC connects to the Internet with no problems.
2. **Damaged/Broken cable** - I tried both cables I have on my old computer, and they're just fine.
3. **Network Adapters collision** - I only have that NIC installed on MotherBoard, no additional network cards
4. **NIC hardware failure** - most of the tech forums I searched through trying to fix this problem, have users saying that you can test whether your card is physically OK if you can ping itself(loop-back), and pinging 127.0.0.1 works just fine.
5. **Dust** - yes, I even tried blowing(no pun intended)
6. **BIOS** - I tried loading optimized defaults, no go. I checked whether OnBoard LAN is enabled, and it indeed is.
7. **Drivers** - Tried both Windows update drivers and manufacturer drivers(both old, that came with the motherboard, and latest update for Realtek Ethernet on their website).
8. **Resetting WinSock** - `netsh winsock reset C:\resetlog.txt`, no go. However, I didn't get the log, not sure why.
9. **FlushDNS/RENEW** - Doesn't work due to media being disconnected(ie. not connected to any networks)
10. **Re-enabling Local Area Connection/Removing it/** - No go.
11. **Uninstalling device using device manager/look for new hardware/install drivers** - No go.

That covers most of what I have tried so far, but no luck. Now, let me show you my IP config:

[image: CMD output]

EDIT:

I also tried it on Ubuntu(Live CD). It doesn't report any errors, but it still doesn't connect. Then I stumbled upon [THIS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194693&p=12878745#post12878745), on ubuntu forums, and the problem for this guy was that the drivers that were loaded were made for a different kernel. Then I checked my NIC's ID in linux' lspci, and it says: `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411`, so I downloaded appropriate drivers for Windows(I couldn't try them on Ubuntu as I was running the Live CD so it wasn't possible for me to remove/add drivers), and it still doesn't work.

Also, WRT NIC blinking yellow/green: I noticed it blinks 4 times rapidly when I start my computer(seems like it starts blinking when computer starts initializing hardware), and no blinking past that point. I expected to see some blinking when NIC tries to find a network(i.e. when OS is loaded and loader circle appears over network icon in system tray), but it doesn't blink.

Comment: Are there blinking lights on the nic? Also, with some odder issues, I found leaving my PC unplugged overnight. Damn if I know why.

Comment: I tried leaving it unplugged for 30 mins with removed battery, and pressing power button several time(while unplugged) to clear any electricity left out in the loop), didn't help.

WRT blinking: yeah, but it doesn't bling rapidly like as if it's looking to connect to a network, as my other computers do, but it blinks twice every once in a while.

Comment: Have you tried running from an Ubuntu Live DVD to test networking?  This could be a driver issue...

Comment: Just tried, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds dead to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've posted (especially same issues on Ubuntu) points to a dead NIC. RMA the board.

Comment: Just checked with service, it surely is.